# How to get the last inserted id in a Linq To Sql custom sql expression?

Tags: linq-to-sql, t-sql

Here is my problem.
I'd like to get the last inserted Id with a custom sql expression in Linq To Sql.

My insert method:

```
public int Add(string Label)
{
    _dbContext.ExecuteCommand("INSERT INTO Products (Label) VALUES (@Label);", Label);

    _dbContext.SubmitChanges();

    var lastId = _dbContext.ExecuteQuery<int>("SELECT Scope_Identity() as [Scope_Identity];").ToList()[0];

    return  lastId;
}
```

lastId always returns null. When I tried this query (Insert + Select) directly in Sql Server, it works perfectly and returns the last inserted Id.
I don't want to use a procedure and I can't use a new Product object (it is not possible for me to use InsertOnSubmit or whatever).

Can you please help me ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've found how to do it:

```
public int Add(string Label)
{
   var query = String.Format("INSERT INTO Products (Label) VALUES (@Label); SELECT ProductId FROM Products WHERE ProductId = Scope_Identity();", Label);

   var lastId = _dbContext.ExecuteQuery<int>(query).ToList()[0];

   return  lastId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
INSERT INTO Products (Label) OUTPUT inserted.ProductID VALUES (@Label);
```

Rob

Comment: Thanks for reply. But it doesn't work. I'm not able to retrieve the output in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

I know that you've already answered but there is anouther way of doing it which I found which was useful for my particular scenerio which involved needing to edit the latest records added to a table without knowing there ids:

```
public int Add(string Label)
{
    var query = String.Format("INSERT INTO Products (Label) VALUES (@Label);", Label);
    _dbContext.ExecuteCommand(query);
    var lastId = _dbContext.ExecuteQuery<int>("SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('Products ')").First();


    return  lastId;
}
```