# Get last inserted row in sql server that has id as primary key and is a identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have tried in several ways a linq query to retrieve the last row inserted in a sql server table.

I need somenthing like this

```
var lastId = from u in context.sistema_Documentos where u.id == max select u;
```

Some people says it is not possible, some says It is not safe or affect performance drastically .. How could I perform this query?

Ps.. would be this a good approach?

```
var lastId = from u in context.sistema_Documentos orderby u.id descending select u.id;
```

Comment: Does this question help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220992/how-to-get-the-last-inserted-id-in-a-linq-to-sql-custom-sql-expression

Comment: This method is absolutely unsafe in a high usage system. How are you attempting to go about it, and what do you need it for? Are you performing an insert and simply need the ID that was inserted?

Comment: It is immediately after inserting the entity or it is not related?

Comment: I'd store a datetime against each row if I really wanted to know when each was inserted, not sure i'd want to just rely on the value of an auto-increment identity column.

Comment: you want to calling `scope_identity()` function immediately after the `insert`. What is `context` here? EF or linq-to-sql?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The identity value, that you are looking for, is available after you did the `SubmitChanges()` method. You can read it like so:

```
context.InsertOnSubmit(entityToInsert);
context.SubmitChanges();
Var lastinsertedId = entityToInsert.Id;
```

Comment: I was prepping this answer after I made my comment above, but work intruded and I missed my window :)

Comment: @JoelEtherton - Yeah, I know. I always have this problem at work.

Answer (score 2):

No performance problems, plain and simple query:

```
var lastId = (from u context.sistema_Documentos
             Select u.id).Max();
```

However, this might not be the right approach if your scenario is that you want to set some kind of master-detail relationship in one uppdate. In that case, you should use the entity itsself. And as Joel mentions, it is not always returning the last...

Eg.

```
context.InsertOnSumbit(masterEntity)
detail.masterEntity = masterEntity
context.InsertOnSubmit(detail)
SubmitChanges()...
```

This will handle the PK/FK assignments properly and within one transaction.

Comment: In a high usage system this method is unsafe. If you have many insertions it's possible to get an incorrect id.

Comment: True, I did not read the "last inserted", this approach is indeed showing the maximum id.

Comment: bad idea, what if somebody else inserted just after you?

Comment: @Jodrell : read my update. OP's pseudo code is what I altered to work in Linq. It is not functionally per sé the last one inserted but it is the one with the highest Id at the point of execution

Comment: The point is, one of the primary reasons for using a database is to allow concurrenct access to data, right? So multiple users could be trying to insert or delete data at the same time. Getting the max id with a query, even immediately after you've sumbited an insert, needn't be the id you just inserted. Another row could have been inserted, your row could have been deleted, the identity seed could have been altered and another row inserted. You can't know.

Comment: @jodrell - I believe I have answered the question (judging from the query, not the text). Also I have provided context. But please show your solution.